# BigTable docker image startup issue: util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform

Tags: hadoop, docker, boot2docker, bigtable, google-cloud-bigtable

I am following the tutorial on BigTable: https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-shell-quickstart

When I try to start my Docker image, I get the following error:

C:\dev\GoogleCloudBigtable-quickstart>docker run -it bigtable-hbase /bin/bash -c "hbase shell"

```
2015-05-07 18:11:52,366 WARN  [main] util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... 
    using builtin-java classes where applicable NativeException: java.io.IOException: 
    java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    initialize at /hbase/bin/../lib/ruby/hbase/hbase.rb:41
    (root) at /hbase/bin/../bin/hirb.rb:118

2015-05-07 18:11:52,958 WARN  [Thread-3] hbase.BigtableOptionsFactory: 
    Shutdown is commencing and you have open 1 connections. 
    Data could be lost if there are ongoing requests.
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I tried this on Mac OSX 10.8.5 and got the same error :-(

Answer (score 1):

It is common to see the Warning about the **native-hadoop** library.
You can fix this by following these [instructions](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#hadoop.native.lib). However, it isn't nescessary for the examples to run.

The next error about hbase.rb, is often shown when your hbase-site.xml is incorrect.

There are three four things that you need to run locally:

- You need to copy the credentials you created to the same folder as keys.json (or edit the Dockerfile to the correct name).
- You need to set your ProjectID, ClusterID, and Zone in the hbase-site.xml

If any of these are incorrect, you will see that error.

It is also common to see the warning **hbase.BigtableOptionsFactory: Shutdown is commencing and you have open xx connections.**, it is benign in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

We also have to make sure that client VM is created with proper bigtable scopes. You can follow below documentation for defining proper scope.

```
https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/creating-vm-instance
```

gcloud command to create instance with proper big table scopes

```
$ gcloud compute instances create cloud-bigtable-vm --scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigtable.admin.table,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigtable.data,storage-ro --zone us-central1-b
```